# Why I cannot ask further questions?

Tags: discussion

It seems that my questions are reasonably well received. Not very. But I got an answer and stuffs.

https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Yet I have reached question limit.

Is the limit too tight or what?

Where can I see deleted questions again? None are deleted

Answer (score 1):

You can see deleted questions in your [profile](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/2086/user4951?tab=questions&sort=votes). Unfortunately, many of yours are deleted and negatively voted. That is the contributing factor to the automatic block. Of the 33 questions you have asked, 18 of those are deleted (all with a score of 0 or below).

Comment: WHere in my profile it is located?

As far as I know, my most recent questions are not blocked.

Is there a sample of question that I can review and ask what's wrong?

Comment: The link in my answer is to your profile.

Comment: @Andy users cannot see their deleted posts on their profile unless they have over 2k rep or the posts have been deleted within the last 60 days.